# Different coding sets in database and website

Tags: database, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a website with very simple news system (posting, editting, deleting etc). All my html pages are saved in UTF-8 formatting, everything displayes correctly.

I specify using UTF in every header:

For saving news to database, I use simple scripts like (all values come from a html form):

```
   $newsTitel   = isset($_POST['title']) ? $_POST['title'] : 'Untitled';
   $submitDate  = $date = date('Y/m/d');
   $content = isset($_POST['newstext']) ? $_POST['newstext'] : 'No content';

   include 'includes/dbconnect.php';

   mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
   mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 
   $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO news SET date='$submitDate',subject='$newsTitel',news='$content'");
```

The data get saved to database but in a weird format (coding). There are characters like **Ã ¡ Ä** etc which makes the content almost unreadable. Other problem is that when loading this content back to html forms (for editting news) it displays in this weird coding. When I looked into the specification of the database I use, it says that it saves data in UTF-8.

I use phpMyAdmin to access the MYSQL database.

So to sum it up:
**Pages:** saved in UTF8, all have correct header
**Database:** interaction with the server: utf8_czech_ci, tables in the same format

What I do not understand at all is this strange bevaior:
1) I save the data into the database using the script above
2) I take a look into phpMyAdmin and see broken encoding
3) I load the data back into my website and display them using this:

```
<?php
        include 'includes/dbconnect.php';
        $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC limit 20") or die(mysql_error()); 

        while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
        {
            echo '<article><h3> '.$info['subject'].'</h3><div id="date">'.$info['date'].'</div>';
            echo '<p>'.$info['news']. '</p></article>';
        } 
 ?>
```

The encoding is correct and no weird characters are displayed.

4) I load the exact same data into a html form (for edition purposes) and see the same broken encoding as in the database.

What happened? I really dont get it. I tried fixing this by re-saving everything in utf8, alterign tables and changing their encodings into different utf8 versions etc...

This is example of a data I pass to the database (it is in czech with html tags):

```
<p>Vařila myšička kašičku</p>
<img src="someImage.jpg">
<p>Další text</p>
```

Thanks for any help...

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commands for specifying the character set should be:

```
set names 'utf8';
```

If you check the result returned from your queries at the moment, what does it say? If I try it in the monitor I get the following:

```
mysql> set names 'UTF-8';
ERROR 1115 (42000): Unknown character set: 'UTF-8'
```

Have you tried using `set names 'utf8'` before connecting for the `SELECT` as well? The characters you're saying are output make me think you're getting back the correct bytes for UTF-8, but they're being interpreted as ISO-8859-1.

Comment: Yeah, I see the same error now... The command was not there before (it was part of my effort to solve the problem...

Comment: Okey, I just corrected this command - now data in my db are saved correctly and the data loaded back are wrongly encoded... what now?

Comment: Thanks man, I will try to put this command before every query and will let you know how it turned out... but this seems like the root of my problem :-)

Comment: Great! I'm sure there will be a global option somewhere, but PHP isn't my forte.

Comment: Great, it works (havent tried with the html form yet, but I guess it will be okay... :-) small mistakes are the worst ones xD

Comment: When you start seeing those capital A's with accents, it's often UTF-8 bytes being interpreted as Latin-1. In my experience, at any rate.

Answer (score 0):

You are not escaping single quotes or some other html chars.
Use  mysql_real_escape_string.

```
$newsTitel   = isset($_POST['title']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']) : 'Untitled';
```

Comment: nice tip but thats not the problem... when I load it and display it with echo or rewrite it directly in my database to some "readable" text, it displays incorrectly in mz webpage...